# Threejs css3d image objects change position after cached

Tags: three.js

When I place `css3d` image objects in the scene. It looks fine, but after some repeated loading, the position of the images seems to be altered.
And also the `css3d` objects appear differently in chrome and firefox.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or some code to show? How do you expect help without showing some code?

Comment: Please add some details. How can we ever answer a question with so little information about the problem.